# how to do hover over image then image blurred and overlay text appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making portfolio website and I tried this code and it worked

```
<div id="nytimes" class="portfolio-thumbnail" style="left: 100px; top: 80px;">

  <span class="text">
      NY times magazine: Table of Contents
  </span>
<img src="images/nytimes.png" alt="">
</div>
```

with this js

```
function toggleOverlay(){
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var specialBox = document.getElementById('specialBox');
overlay.style.opacity = .8;
if(overlay.style.display == "block"){
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    specialBox.style.display = "none";
} else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    specialBox.style.display = "block";
}
```

}

it works like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mkpha

however, i tried to use responsive grid but then i am not sure how to incorporate the function of image blurred and text overlay appears with this code here.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="images/nytimes.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x600" class="img-responsive">     </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x600" class="img-responsive"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any easy way to do hover over function (blurred img with overlay text)?

Comment: can you mock something up on codepen.io so that I can I have a look?

Comment: @ramesh http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mkpha

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would want to use javascript if you simply want to have a text overlay, on hovering over a specific div. I am still not certain if this is what you want to achieve, but I did a simple mock-up on what I understood from your question:

http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/DqKLj

let me know if this not what you were trying to achieve

Comment: thank you! but how can i put them in side of the last code example? because i am using the bootstrap grid system so that i need to use div class = "col-xs-4"